# How to render date field in UI component (in php not xml) in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, date

How to render date field in UI component(in php not xml)   in magento 2

I am building form as in the catalog (meta arrays), datetime eav attributes.

I have tried like below

```
 'date_of_stock' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => array(
                                        'formElement' =>Input::DATE,
                                        'componentType' => Field::DATE,
                                        'dataType' => Text::DATE,
                                        'label' => __('Date Back In Stock'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'date_of_stock',
                                        'require' => '1',
                                    ),
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
```

But it throws undefined constant error? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there you can use this below code to create date as input field

```
'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
         'config'   => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
            'id' => 'dob',
            'options' => [
                'changeYear'=> true,
                'changeMonth'=> true,
                'yearRange' => '1950:2050',
            ],
         ],
         'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true
         ],
         'label' => __('Date of Birth'),
         'required' => true,
         'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.dob',
         'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
         'visible' => true,
         'sortOrder' => 55
         ];
```

Comment: thank you @Vikas